# Place an IFRAME tag inside a DIV tag

Tags: c#, html

I have an HTML string that contains many HTML tags including iframe:

```
<iframe width="40" other-properties>
   iframe code
</iframe>
```

How can I place all iframe tags in the HTML string into a DIV as follows:

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="40" other-properties>
     iframe code
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @KieranQuinn, why have HTML in a server-side string, for that matter?

Comment: The HTML string comes from a database ... The HTML string was inserted through a CMS.

Comment: How are you currently passing that string (assuming there is one string and not many) to the dom? If at all

Comment: And why do you want to put it inside a DIV?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit To be able to make a you tube video responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `Replace` looks like enough

```
var newString = originalString.Replace("<iframe", "<div class='video'><iframe").Replace("</iframe>", "</iframe></div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for this.

It even works on elements that are not yet added to the DOM:

```
var $html = $('<section><h1>Test</h1><iframe width="40"></iframe></section>');
$html.find('iframe').wrap('<div>');

// now you can append $html to the DOM

console.log($html[0].outerHTML); // Outputs: <section><h1>Test</h1><div><iframe width="40"></iframe></div></section>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fstey08m/).